# jQuery to perform an action when all radiobuttons with a particular class have been checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have to develop a Question Template, which loads 3 questions on the page at a time. When the 3 questions have all been answered(with their radiobuttons selected), it moves on to the next section. Here is the code for the inputs:

```html
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>

<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>

<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
```

I want to make sure that once a radiobutton with the name 'q_1', 'q_2' and 'q_3' is selected from 'section_1', we move to section two. How would I approach this problem with a simple jquery code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the change event:

- You can use [:radio selector](https://api.jquery.com/radio-selector/)
- $(':radio[name^="q_"].section_1') select all radios with class section_1 and name starting with q_ (so, in your case, q_1, q_2 and q_3).
- [change](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event because:

  > ...radio buttons, the event is fired immediately when the user makes a selection....
- test if all radios are checked:    $(':radio[name^="q_"].section_1:checked').length == 3

```js
$(function () {
  $(':radio[name^="q_"].section_1').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($(':radio[name^="q_"].section_1:checked').length == 3) {
      console.log('ALL required are checked!');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
<br>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
<br>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think no issue in your code but just consider one thing, html5 “required” attributes works only in above IE8.

You can use http://caniuse.com/ site for check html5 attributes work on which browser.

Please check your code with below code.

```
  <form action="HtmlPage1.html">
    <input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value="1" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value="0.75" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value="0.5" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value="0.25" required>

    <input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value="1" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value="0.75" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value="0.5" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value="0.25" required>

    <input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value="1" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value="0.75" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value="0.5" required>
    <input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value="0.25" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Next" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Listen to `change` event on elements with class that starts with "selection_".

Count the radio buttons sets (hold the unique name values in an array) and check if any of these sets do not have an checked radio button.

Note that this should work on any number of radio buttons (do not have to be 3 sets of 4 buttons).

Another point is that the inputs must have only one class assigned.

```
$('[class^="selection_"][type="radio"]').on('change', function() {
    var className = $(this).attr('class');

    // Hold the unique name values in 'names' array
    var names = [];
    $('[class^="selection_"][type="radio"]').each(function() {
       var n = $(this).attr('name');
       if ($.inArray(n, names) == -1) {
          names.push(n);
       }
    }); 

    // Check if there are any unchecked radio buttons for each name set
    var unanswered = 0;  
    for (var nm in names) {
       if (!$('.' + className + '[name="' + names[nm] + '"]').is(':checked')) {
          unanswered++;
       }
    }

    // If no unswered set exists, procceed to next set!
    if (unanswered == 0) {
       proceedToNextQuestionSet();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What I have understood from your question, I have created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sehsxozL/) as an answer. Kindly check it.

```js
$(function(){

$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){

if($('input[type="radio"]:checked').length==3)
{
 //do something
 console.log("3 radio buttons are checked")
}


})

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
<br>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
<br>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
q_1
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_1' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
</br>
q_2
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_2' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>
</br>
q_3
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=1 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.75 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.5 required>
<input type='radio' name='q_3' class='section_1' value=0.25 required>

<button id="btn_check"> submit
</button>
```

javascript

```
$("#btn_check").click(function(){
var q1_ans = $("input[name='q_1']:checked").val();
var q2_ans = $("input[name='q_2']:checked").val();
var q3_ans = $("input[name='q_3']:checked").val();
if(q1_ans > 0 && q2_ans > 0 && q3_ans> 0){
alert("move on to next steps")
}else{
alert("please complete all question");
}
});
```

[jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/wx38rz5L/1231/)